# How to wait for the result of an asynchronous query

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, asynchronous

I'm trying my hand at NodeJS server programming in Typscript and I'm having trouble handling asynchronous queries. My server needs to communicate with a MongoDB database running locally.

Here are my communication functions:

```
export const connect = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_HOST!);
        console.log(ansicolor.lightBlue(`[i] Connected to MongoDB at: ${process.env.DB_HOST}`));
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.error(ansicolor.red('[!] Error connecting to MongoDB:'), ansicolor.red(error.message));
        process.exit(1);
    }
};

export const createClient = async (hwid: string, ip: string): Promise<number> => {
    const RSAKeys = await generateRSAKeys() as { privateKey: string, publicKey: string };

    try {
        const newInstance = new client({
            hwid: hwid,
            ip: ip,
            publicKeyRSA: RSAKeys.publicKey,
            privateKeyRSA: RSAKeys.privateKey,
        });

        await newInstance.save();
        return 0;
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.error(ansicolor.red('[!] Error creating client:'), ansicolor.red(error));
        return -1;
    }
};

export const isExisting = async (hwid: string): Promise<boolean> => {
    try {
        const existingClient = await client.findOne({ hwid: hwid }).exec();
        return !!existingClient;
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.error(ansicolor.red('[!] Error checking client existence:'), ansicolor.red(error));
        return false;
    }
};

export const getStatus = async (hwid: string): Promise<string> => {
    try {
        const existingClient = await client.findOne({ hwid: hwid}).exec();
        if (existingClient) {
            return existingClient.status || "NULL";
        } else {
            console.error(ansicolor.red(`[!] Client not found for HWID: ${hwid}`));
            return "NULL";
        }
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.error(ansicolor.red(`[!] Client not found for HWID: ${hwid} error:`), ansicolor.red(error));
        return "NULL";
    }

export const updateSatus = async (hwid: string, status: string): Promise<number> => {
    try {
        const result = await client.updateOne({ hwid: hwid }, { $set: { status: status } });

        if (result.modifiedCount > 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            console.error(ansicolor.red(`[!] Client not found for HWID: ${hwid}`));
            return -1;
        }
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.error(ansicolor.red('[!] Error updating client status:'), ansicolor.red(error));
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I specify that I use `mongoose` for the database connection and `dotenv`for env's constants the other modules are not linked to these operations.

Here is my test function:

```
server.listen(port, async () => {
    connect();
    console.info(ansicolor.lightBlue(`[i] Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`));

    createClient('Test', '127.0.0.1');
    let status = await getStatus("Test");
    console.log(`Current status : ${status}\n`);

    await updateSatus('Test', 'busy');
    status = await getStatus("Test");
    console.log(`Updated status : ${status}\n`);
});
```

Here's my console output:

```
[i] Server is running on http://localhost:3000
[i] Connected to MongoDB at: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/clients
[!] Client not found for HWID: Test
Current status : NULL

[!] Client not found for HWID: Test
Updated status : waiting
```

When I consult the DB via MongoDBCompass, I realize that the client has been created. I guess I'm not handling asynchronous queries properly.

I'd like my code to wait for queries to return before manipulating them.

Comment: Does `await createClient('Test', '127.0.0.1');` help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before getting the status of the client can occur, you must wait for the connect and creation of the client to finish.

```js
server.listen(port, async () => {
    await connect();
    console.info(ansicolor.lightBlue(`[i] Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`));

    await createClient('Test', '127.0.0.1');
    let status = await getStatus("Test");
    console.log(`Current status : ${status}\n`);

    await updateSatus('Test', 'busy');
    status = await getStatus("Test");
    console.log(`Updated status : ${status}\n`);
});
```

As a side note, `await newInstance.save()` results in the created object, so if you were to return this, you wouldn't necessarily need to perform the proceeding `getStatus`.

See mongoose `Model.prototype.save()` doc for example:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.prototype.save()